# Does cygwin support the ftruncate POSIX standard?

Tags: cygwin, posix

I am not sure if Cygwin supports [`ftruncate`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). Can someone please throw some light on this/ point me in the right direction ?

This is the version of cygwin I am on:

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW pluto 2.9.0(0.318/5/3) 2017-09-12 10:41 i686 Cygwin
```

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried ?

If you look at the documentation 
https://cygwin.com/cygwin-api/compatibility.html#std-susv4

`ftruncate` is included

Comment: Thanks... that helps !!